# Run a Specific Function Depending on Which Drop-Down was Chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code I found to try and make this drop down menu. http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut183.shtml

Ignore my variables and values, they are all place holders.

For example, when I hit submit it runs the "gen" function.

Is there anyway I can have my code run a different function based on which drop-down option was selected?

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="doublecombo" form action"index.php" method="POST">
<p><select name="example" size="1" onChange="redirect(this.options.selectedIndex)">
<option>Amazon</option>
<option>Apple</option>
<option>Logitech</option>
<option>Nike</option>
</select>
<select name="stage2" size="1">
<option value="http://javascriptkit.com">Kindle Fire</option>
<option value="http://www.news.com">Kindle DX</option>
<option value="http://www.wired.com">Kindle Charger</option>
<option value="http://www.microsoft.com">Kindle Paperweight</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="test" value="Generate"
onClick="gen()">
</p>

<script>
var groups=document.doublecombo.example.options.length
var group=new Array(groups)
for (i=0; i<groups; i++)
group[i]=new Array()

group[0][0]=new Option("Kindle Fire","http://javascriptkit.com")
group[0][1]=new Option("Kindle DX","http://www.news.com")
group[0][2]=new Option("Kindle Charger","http://www.wired.com")
group[0][2]=new Option("Kindle Paperweight","http://www.microsoft.com")

group[1][0]=new Option("MacBook","http://www.cnn.com")
group[1][1]=new Option("iPhone","http://www.abcnews.com")
group[1][2]=new Option("iPad","http://www.yahoo.com")
group[1][3]=new Option("iMac","http://www.apple.com")

group[2][0]=new Option("G602 Wireless Gaming Mouse","http://www.hotbot.com")
group[2][1]=new Option("G19s Gaming Keyboard","http://www.infoseek.com")
group[2][2]=new Option("G430 Surround Sound Gaming Headset","http://www.excite.com")
group[2][3]=new Option("PowerShell Controller","http://www.lycos.com")

group[3][0]=new Option("Nike FuelBand","http://www.nike.com")

var temp=document.doublecombo.stage2

function redirect(x){
for (m=temp.options.length-1;m>0;m--)
temp.options[m]=null
for (i=0;i<group[x].length;i++){
temp.options[i]=new Option(group[x][i].text,group[x][i].value)
}
temp.options[0].selected=true
}

function gen(){
location=temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value
}

function exampleFunction(){
}

function anotherExampleFunction(){
}
</script>

</form>
</html>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Jquery's event handlers](https://api.jquery.com/on):

```
$(selector).on('click', gen); 
$(selector).on('change', redirect);
```

These also have the following short-hands:

```
$(selector).click(gen); 
$(selector).change(redirect);
```

Where selector is the element you want to attach the listeners too, by id or class or element name or other types of [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

In the case of `select` you can only use the `change` event. Look at the examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

Here is an example of what you are looking for: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v6wRY/4/)

```
var functions = {
    func1: function(){console.log("func1 called")},
    func2: function(){console.log("func2 called")},
    func3: function(){console.log("func3 called")},
}

$( "select" )
  .change(function () {
    var selected = $( "select option:selected" );
    functions[selected.val()]();
  })
  .change();
```

I select the `select` element, and attach a `change` event handler to it. When it changes, the handler functions selects the selected option (`select option:selected` means the selected `option` which is a child of `select`), then I simply call the functions from the functions object according to the `options`'s `value`.

Comment: Please excuse my bare knowledge of Jquery, but will that handler work if I have a function for every option in the drop-down?

Comment: You can do whatever you want. The `$` selector can attach the listeners to all matched elements, so if you have several elements with the same class, it can attach the same function to all of them at once, or different functions for different elements. Read the part about selectors. For example, http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/. This one enables you to pick specific children of an element and you can append different functions to each. Or you can just do individual id's using `$('#id')` You are only limited by how much you are willing to learn.

Comment: Added a working example of one possibility how this might work.